# Jtable header size in netbeans

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans, jtable

Hi Guys i ve this Table in Netbeans and the Data it comes from the database i have many rows so i activate a scrollbar but the problem stays in the Title this is the Problem 
[enter link description here](http://hpics.li/c80cce0)

and i wanna the Result be like that 
[enter link description here](http://hpics.li/2343654)
any solutions ? Please

Comment: Please improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to size the width of the columns then check out [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/)

It allows you to size the columns based on:

1. the header width
2. the data width
3. maximum of header or data

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
table_name.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(474);
```